# webpack export JavaScript class and use in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am using `webpack` and trying to use a class exported in HTML.
I am getting error when I try to access the class in HTML.

Below is the example code.

```
// src/app.js
// I have other imports 

export class MyClass {
   constructor() {

   }
   
   foo() {
      console.log('In Foo');
   }
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'MyClass',
  }
};
```

```
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const obj = new MyClass();
    obj.foo();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor
```

Also if I have multiple classes, variables and function then how can I export from JavaScript and access from HTML?

Answer (score 1):

For compiling a library with Webpack:

```js
 output: {
    library: { type: 'umd' }
 }
```

Comment: I did added 'type' as 'umd' but still getting same error. I did try multiple combinations but still getting error.

Comment: @User7723337 the only thing needed in `output` is the line I added in my answer. IOW, don't add, but replace it fully with it.